# How to fix VBA MS Access Error 462 in Setting Range?

Tags: excel, charts, runtime-error, ms-access-2016

On 1/11/2018 I requested here for help to include and move labels on the Chart bars. 
However, I received two answers that did not help me find a solution.
Therefore, I googled again many pages, without success.
Then I started to try some VBA code instructions.
First, I have `.SeriesCollection(1) and .SeriesCollection(2)`running well
I decided to add `.SeriesColletion(3)`that generated the third bar.
In the third bars, I inserted labels and then '.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse'.
In the third bars, I inserted labels and then `.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse`

Now the `xlBarStack` Chart shows bars and labels with values ​​that I need.
However, I'm not sure if the coding for the three `.SeriesCollection`  is optimal and safe to run without errors. 
Therefore, I appreciate it if someone here can help me.

In addition, sometimes when I run the code for the second time VBA displays the message `Error 462 Remote server computer does not exist or is not available`.

The error always occurs here:

```
Set a = Range ("A2: A" & Rows.Count)
```

Those lines of code are added in:

Set a = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count) 
Set a = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)', 'Set b = Range("A2:B" & Rows.Count)

The variables a and b are dimensioned by:

Dim a As Excel.Range,  Dim b As Excel.Range

For this code, I previously tested 
`On Error GoTo errortrap` after dimensioning the variables and
 `Exit Sub`
errortrap: MsgBox Err.Description` before End Sub.
But the chart was no created. 
How can I fix Error 462?
Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496294/error-462-in-vba-remote-server-machine-not-found ?

Comment: @Michal Rosa. I really appreciate your quick reply 
I checked these links, but, I did not find the code lines in the examples on how to correct my Error.
Also, I did not read that Thomas Mathew indicated that he solved the Error.
Can you give more details to fix my error?
Cheers

Comment: Please, can someone help me to fix Error 462? Cheers.