# Open a website and autofill information from an array

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, autofill

I'm new to VBA, and I just looked up how to autofill data from excel to a certain database (I referred to this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=docnLSdj8rI)--I tried other references, but for a newbie, this was the easiest to digest. None of the cases here in SO seemed to fit my scenario, so I thought I'd finally ask.

This is my code so far (I changed the URL of the company website as it is confidential):

```
Sub autofill()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    
    IE.navigate "http://tools.filings.irc.company.com/ust/upload/2"
    
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState  4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    
    For intRow = 2 To 5 'or until the last row that still has data, I don't know how to code it that way
    
        IE.document.getElementById("global_CompanyName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & intRow).Value
    
        doc.getElementById("ddDIVTextContainer").Value = Manila
    
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Side note: Code is still incomplete by the way! Haven't written it out for all fields because I keep getting an error 462.

Whenever I press run, it actually opens the company database website on IE, but it doesn't fill any field out. It turns out that I get error 462, which says The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable. I then press debug, and the thing highlights "Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4" (I get that VBA is case sensitive, and for some reason it automatically makes some upper case letters lowercase (like IE.document instead of IE.Document, IE.readyState instead of IE.ReadyState).)

Any chance I can do something about this? Just to explain, my idea is to have an array where each individual row holds a series of information that the macro will have to input onto the database, much like in the photos below. If there's a way I can also have the macro upload a PDF by linking it from my local drive, that'd also be great!

[Here is a picture of the table array I'm planning the macro references the data from to automatically fill out the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIozJ.png)

[Here is a photo of the company database website where we have to manually enter the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wolJY.png)

I know it's a tough ask, but if you can, please explain things to me in layman's terms. I'm still trying to understand basic concepts, but if I get this done it'd be immensely helpful to my teammates and myself. Cheers!

Comment: Without a reproductible example, it is difficult to be helped for a specific problem like yours.

Comment: the information that I provided is all that I could provide, sadly. The website is a proprietary tool, so I'd get in trouble if I share it. But also, even if you did theoretically have the link to the site database, you still wouldn't be able to test the code there because it requires to login with credentials, which only employees have. :( I would honestly provide more information, but I also can't :(

Comment: I do  not have a problem with that. I tried suggesting that you may have...

Comment: Have you asked said company if they perhaps provide an API which you could use instead?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea what that is, but I will ask my boss tomorrow (he's on leave today) -- I'll get back to you on that! :) But may I ask what the API's for? :O

Comment: It's `Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState  4` in your code. I think it should be `Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4`. Besides, for the 462 error you got, you can refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs-6647c4b4-da5c-ee1f-cc6f-58815d47702d) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496294/error-462-in-vba-remote-server-machine-not-found). Please kill all the IE process using this command line: `taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe` and test again. Besides, you need to free your variables in the end of the code.