# Runtime error 462 when saving word file from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I have an excel sheet that is to create numerous word files while looping through the code. After pasting data från excel, the word files are to be named and saved to the hard drive. The first iteration goes perfect, but on the second I get a Runtime error 462 just before saving the word file.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Kopiera_Excel_Till_Word(FilVag As String)

Selection.Copy

Dim appWord As Word.Application

Set appWord = New Word.Application

Dim FilNamnVag As String

With appWord

.Visible = True

.Activate

End With

appWord.Documents.Add

appWord.Activate

appWord.Selection.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

With appWord

.Visible = True

.Activate

End With

'****It runs this far the second iteration, then I get Runtime error 462*****

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 filename:= _
    FilVag, FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
    :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
    :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
    SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False

appWord.Quit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 462 in VBA : remote server machine not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496294/error-462-in-vba-remote-server-machine-not-found)

Comment: The link referenced above indeed contains the hint for the solution: "modify the code so each call to an Excel object, method, or property is qualified with the appropriate object variable". Towards the end of your code, change `ActiveDocument.SaveAs2` into `appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2` and `ActiveDocument.Close` into `appWord.ActiveDocument.Close` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! It solves the 462 but I kepp getting a 5152 instead, on the very same spot in the code...

Comment: Check that FilVag doesn't contain any characters that might cause a problem, such as `|?*<>":` or `/` within the filename element.

Answer (score 0):

When working in VBA it pays to be specific rather than rely on objects such as `ActiveDocument`

```
Sub Kopiera_Excel_Till_Word(FilVag As String)

    Selection.Copy

    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Set appWord = New Word.Application

    Dim FilNamnVag As String

    Dim docWord As Word.Document
    Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Add

    docWord.Range.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    docWord.SaveAs2 Filename:= _
        FilVag, FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
        :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
        :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    docWord.Close SaveChanges:=False
    appWord.Quit
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```